# Verify file permissions

Tags: permissions, filesystems, btrfs

I did a fresh installation of OpenSUSE and copied all my files from the old home directory. The user and group names hadn't changed, and all the files seem to have proper permissions.

However, I ran into couple of strange issues, and it left me wondering how to make sure the file system permissions are correct. What's the best way to do that?

I just want to make sure there aren't any weird dangling permissions or security contexts that might be causing trouble.

- OS: OpenSUSE Leap 42.1
- FS: BTRFS

Answer (score 0):

If you used rsync, possibly including --numeric-ids to preserve numeric ids, then things should just be right already. If you want to verify it, try dumping the permissions using stat, eg.

```
find . -exec stat -c "%n %a %A" {} + | sort > oldpermissions.txt
```

and then the same on the other machine, then you can diff the files to compare.